# gnu make: use wildcard twice in rule dependency

Tags: cmake, makefile, gnu-make, pandoc

I would like to have a couple of make rules of the form

```
build/file_a.pdf: text/file_a/file_a.md
    pandoc -o build/file_a.pdf text/file_a/file_a.md

build/file_b.pdf: text/file_b/file_b.md
    pandoc -o build/file_b.pdf text/file_a/file_b.md

...
```

to convert a couple of markdown files to PDF whenever I change them. I think specifying a rule like

```
build/%.pdf: text/%/%.md
    ....
```

is not working. Is there a way of generating a rule matching the special pattern I have? Are such cases better handled by cmake?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate your rules dynamically with [`define`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes), [`eval`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function), and [`call`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function).

```
define build_rule
    build/$1.pdf: text/$1/$1.md
        ....
endef

$(foreach f,file_a file_b,$(eval $(call build_rule,$f)))
```

Comment: You always provide compact-sized solutions :D

Comment: This approach actually works to resolve my problem and if I know the files file_a, file_b .... before writing the makefile. Assuming I don't know the names file_a, file_b beforehand. Is there also a way to define a rule like build/PATTERN.pdf: text/PATTERN/PATTERN.md where PATTERN stands for an arbitrary pattern but always the same one? S.t.  build/file_a.pdf: text/file_a/file_a.md is matched but build/file_a.pdf: text/file_a/file_b.md is not?

Comment: You might be able to do that with secondary expansion but I'm not sure. Other than that I don't know (and can't think of anything clever) to allow that to work. If you can glob (or otherwise discover) the list of files that require this defining that could be used instead of the hard-coded list.